# Python function to import filename and city name

Tags: python, excel, pandas, function

Very new to python and trying my best to learn.  I understand the concept of functions and they don;t seem complicated but for some reason I have the worst time with them.

I have an excel spreadsheet I need to open the file and read data in from a specific sheet w/in the file.

I setup the function like so:

```
def process_data(file, city):
    file_name =  "../data/" + file # path to file + file name
    sheet = city # sheet name 


process_data("Jan 10.xlsx", "Seattle")
```

but it doesn't work.  I ultimately want to read this into a panda dataframe so I can manipulate the data.  Can someone give a newbie a little guidance?

All help is greatly appreciated....

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What is it?

Comment: You're on your way. Next you'll probably want to feed the `file_name` and `sheet` variables into [pd.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). Return the resulting DataFrame so you can do `df = process_data("Jan 10.xlsx", "Seattle")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pandas # if pandas isn't installed 

Import pandas as pd #importing pandas 

df_sheet = pd.read_excel('file_name', 'sheet_name) # creating dataframe
```

First parameter is for the file_name, and second parameter is for the
Sheet name from that excel file. Hope this helps.

Here is the link for official Pandas [read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)